# Index on smalldatetime column

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with the following columns

```
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Timestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Datestamp] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
[Message] [nvarchar](max) NULL
```

There is clustered index and PK on ID column.
There is also non clustered index on Datestamp.

Datastamp column contains date in format like 2021-10-04 00:00:00

What I read is that index on Datestamp column will optimize filtering on date.
Indeed this is the query plan when selecting ID filtered by date.

```
select ID
from [Log]
where [Datestamp] > '2020-01-01' and [Datestamp] < '2021-09-01'
order by datestamp
```

[image: select ID and filter on datestamp]

However when I select Message and filter on Datestamp I can see query plan now involve Sort operator that would make this query non performant.
Also the non clustered index on Datestamp is no longer used.

```
select Message
from [Log]
where [Datestamp] > '2020-01-01' and [Datestamp] < '2021-09-01'
order by datestamp
```

[image: select message and filter on datestamp]

Any idea why this is happening?
Why is the non clustered index being used when selecting the Message column?

Comment: FYI, your smalldatetime is not stored in a display format, its stored as a binary format.

Comment: Probably, because the index only allows SQL Server to find the records, then it has to access the Message column using the clustered index, due to the number of rows in your table SQL Server has decided its faster to scan the table and go directly to the full record. If you try and select a lot less records e.g. for a single month you might find it makes use of the index.

Comment: Something called a tipping point, which is very complex to calculate, see https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2020/05/no-you-cant-calculate-the-tipping-point-with-simple-percentages/ But it might be worth updating statistics just in case the optimizer got it wrong. You can also add `Message` as an `INCLUDE` column in you index, but it's probably overkill

Comment: @DaleK, what do you mean by display vs binary format? Message is not sorted so why is the Sort operator getting along?

Comment: You said "Datastamp column contains date in format like 2021-10-04 00:00:00" which is incorrect, it has no meaningful display format as stored. Your query has `order by datestamp` hence the sort.

Comment: @DaleK, it might be just way of expression here. The column is smalldatetime with zeros for hours, minutes and seconds. That's what I meant.

Comment: @Charlieface, I reduced the period to where [Datestamp] > '2021-10-01' and [Datestamp] < '2021-10-05'. This selects about 1,100 rows out of 36k in total. It should not fall in the tipping point, right?

Comment: And what was the result? You can share query plans via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan @DaleK The scan is as much a problem as the sort, admittedly the sort is more avoidable

Comment: You can only have one clustered index - choose it wisely and carefully. Do NOT assume it must or should be the same as the primary key. Dates in particular, if they never change and are always inserted in order (which is common), are good candidates for clustering. But that decision depends greatly on usage.

Comment: Slight detour but why are you storing date and time in separate columns? That means in order to know which rows occurred on a certain date between two points in time you have to either munge two column together or use two predicates. I would just have a column for LogDate as a datetime.

Comment: @SeanLange this is just the test environment. In production there are millions of rows. I separated the date into separate column in order to improve indexing. My queries are filtering by date only, not by time.

Answer (score 1):

When you select the ID column, the non-clustered index on DateStamp contains:

- the copy of DateStamp column,
- the reference to the primary key, which is clustered index on ID column.

So, when using query:

```
select ID
from [Log]
where [Datestamp] > '2020-01-01' and [Datestamp] < '2021-09-01'
order by datestamp
```

the IX_Log_DateStamp index covers the whole query.

But when you select the Message column in a query:

```
select Message
from [Log]
where [Datestamp] > '2020-01-01' and [Datestamp] < '2021-09-01'
order by datestamp
```

the IX_Log_DateStamp index cannot cover that column.

So there is generated a query plan that uses the fastest option here (for your data) - searching the primary key (clustered index) for filtering by DateStamp column.

The query optimizer does not choose to use the non-clustered index here because there is no reference to the Message column directly. It should use joining the clustered index and searching for the Message column, but it uses the fastest way here - scanning and sorting the clustered index.

If you want to achieve the execution plan:

[image]

you should use INCLUDE in index creating:

```
DROP INDEX [IX_Log_DateStamp] ON [dbo].[Log];
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Log_DateStamp]
ON [dbo].[Log] ([DateStamp] ASC)
INCLUDE([Message])
GO
```